# psql: redirect sql error message to logfile

Tags: postgresql, psql

I need to execute multiple psql statement in a block as below. Here I am using "\o" to redirect query output to "logfile".

But "\o" only redirects query output, it does not include ERROR message if any error occurred.

For example: if I give wrong db_name, then it gives error on screen " ERROR: 'db_name' does not exists". But this error is not stored in given logfile.

Is there any way to save errors in same logfile, where other output is being saved.

```
psql -p 5432 -U postgres -h ${db_host} << eof1
\set ON_ERROR_STOP TRUE
\o | cat >> ${logfile}
\l+ db_name;
select pg_database_size('db_name');
\o
eof1
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that inside `psql`. You'll have to redirect standard error using the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect STDERR to a file:

```
$ psql 2> errors.txt
Expanded display is used automatically.
Null display is "¤".
psql (10.5)
Type "help" for help.

db=# select 1;
 ?column?
----------
        1
(1 row)

db=# select 1 + 'foo';
db=# \q

$ cat errors.txt
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "foo"
LINE 1: select 1 + 'foo';
                   ^
```

You could also specify the output file when invoking psql rather than using `\o`:

```
$ psql -o out.txt 2> errors.txt
Expanded display is used automatically.
Null display is "¤".
psql (10.5)
Type "help" for help.

db=# select 1;
db=# select 1 + 'foo';
db=# \q

$ cat out.txt
 ?column?
----------
        1
(1 row)

$ cat errors.txt
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "foo"
LINE 1: select 1 + 'foo';
                   ^
```

Comment: i found that you need to use error file with full-path; relative as above did not work. Instead of "$ psql 2> errors.txt" you want to say "$ psql 2>/home/<your_rest_of_the_path_here>/errors.txt"