# How to execute multiple SQL files from a local directory in PostgreSQL/PgAdmin4 in on transaction in Windows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, windows, bash

I have a folder in a directory in my PC which contains multiple SQL files. Each of the file is a Postgres function. I want to execute every SQL file situated in the folder at a time in PostgreSQL server using PgAdmin or in other way. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you considered merging these files into a single one, which is fairly straightforward, and then executing it? ;)

Comment: I thought about it but don't know how to do. I want a process by which I can execute all SQL files in PostgreSQL server.  There are 500+ sql files. Currently I have to execute each sql file individually. This is too time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize if I'm oversimplifying your question, but if the main issue is how to execute all SQL files without having to call them one by one, you just need to put them in a loop, e.g. in bash calling `psql`

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.sql
do
  psql -h dbhost -d db -U dbuser -f $f
done
```

Or `cat` them  and pipe the result to `psql` stdin:

```
$ cat /path/to/files/*.sql | psql -h dbhost -d db -U dbuser
```

And if you need them to run in a single transaction, consider merging the SQL files, e.g. using `cat` - this assumes all statements in your sql file are properly terminated:

```
$ cat /path/to/files/*.sql > merged.sql
```

Comment: where to execute the command? Is this solution for windows? My OS is windows..

Comment: @Alien those are linux commands. Look for the equivalent on Windows (`cat` -> `type`?). I haven't touched Windows in ~20 years.

Comment: where to execute the command? In CMD?

Comment: @Alien yes, in the command line terminal of Windows. There is certainly a way to emulate bash commands using windows though: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/use-bash-shell-natively-windows-10/

Comment: and the CMD should be opened under the bin folder where PostgreSQL is installed? like `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin`?

Comment: @Alien no, not necessarily. As long as the psql path in the system variables is properly set, there is no need to be in the bin folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250602/discussion-between-alien-and-jim-jones).

Comment: so can I execute the command using git bash?

Comment: @Alien you have to execute these commands in the Linux bash shell. Since you're on windows, you have to emulate it somehow, as Windows does not use it natively. If I may share a piece of advice -> never run postgres on Windows.

Comment: I am just running postgres on windows in localhost.

Comment: @Alien still it is IMHO a bad idea, as the engine's behaviour might differ from production if it uses Linux (as it should). I've heard a few times something called powershell for windows, you might wanna take a look at that.

Comment: Did it in windows CMD. The equivalent of cat in windows is type. you are right. Thanks a lot @Jim Jones. You saved my times....

Comment: @Alien I'm glad it helped. You can use the same principle to do many things using psql, e.g. this other answer of mine on `copy`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59304818/2275388

Comment: thanks. But unfortunately it executed 669 filed from 776. rest of the files did not get executed.

Comment: @Alien well, it means that either there were errors in the files or they had a different extension `.sql` != `.SQL`

Comment: @ Jim Jones Every files ended with `.sql` . Is there any way to identify if there any error in files? Or can I find out files which are not executed?

Comment: @Alien normally psql shows the errors (if any) in the console itself if something happens. But you can always redirect the errors to `stderr`, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55862605/2275388